# How to get hreflang value in code behind c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-cn" /><br />
```

How to get hreflang value in code behind c#. I tried many ways but still not working.

Comment: _I tried many ways_. Can you add those many ways to your question?

Comment: If you want to send hreflang to the server, you have to serialize the value of the html dom element and submit a form.

Comment: @Hunter If any of the responses have helped you, please mark one as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `<link />` tag a server-side control by adding ID and runat attributes:

```
<link id="AlternateLink" runat="server" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-cn" />
```

You can retrieve the value of the `hreflang` attribute from your code-behind by using this code:

```
string hrefLangAttr = AlternateLink.Attributes["hreflang"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
<link rel="alternate" id="hrid" hreflang="zh-cn" />

    var v = document.getElementById("hrid").hreflang;
```

Comment: How do you think does that answer the question?

Comment: sorry I forgot write ans. :)